# Find which bit of code is moving an iOS UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I don't know how, but after moving two of my UIViews, they are moving back to their starting x/y position every so often.  I've checked the code and I'm not moving them back to their starting positions directly, but they are going back there somehow.

What technique would you suggest to find which bit of code is moving them?

(I am 'hiding' them at one point (alpha=0.5, userInteractionEnabled=NO) and then re-showing them.  That couldn't be it could it?)

Comment: If you're using auto layout and moving views by changing their frames, then when the view needs to redraw itself, its position will revert to that defined by the constraints. That's probably what you're seeing.

Comment: Ah, right.  So I need to either switch off auto-layout (probably won't do that) or adjust the constraints - thanks.  Feel free to convert your comment to an answer.  I'll adjust the question to suit.